NoReverseMatch at /deck/rehearse/22/ using pyttsx3 for flashcard app
I am a newbie to django and pyttsx3 i have coded a flashcard app and want to add text to speech using pyttsx3 however after coding the buttons i am getting the error Reverse for 'text_to_speech' with keyword arguments '{'deck_id': 22, 'card_id': ''}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['deck/rehearse/(?P<deck_id>[0-9]+)/text\-to\-speech/(?P<card_id>[0-9]+)/\Z']. i have checked url patterns and they seem to be fine
I have tried to google the problem with no success I have gone through the code several times but cant find the error any help will be appreciated.
views
import pyttsx3
import os
from django.conf import settings
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404, redirect
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView
from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm
from django.contrib.auth import login, authenticate
from .models import Card, Deck, StudySet, StudentDeck
from .forms import CardForm, DeckForm, CardFormSet

from django.http import JsonResponse
import base64

def text_to_speech(request, deck_id, card_id):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        card = Card.objects.get(id=card_id)
        engine = pyttsx3.init()

        # Generate audio data for the question
        question_audio_data = engine.save_to_file(card.question, 'question.mp3')
        with open('question.mp3', 'rb') as f:
            question_audio_base64 = base64.b64encode(f.read()).decode('utf-8')
        os.remove('question.mp3')

        # Generate audio data for the answer
        answer_audio_data = engine.save_to_file(card.answer, 'answer.mp3')
        with open('answer.mp3', 'rb') as f:
            answer_audio_base64 = base64.b64encode(f.read()).decode('utf-8')
        os.remove('answer.mp3')

        engine.runAndWait()

        return JsonResponse({
            'question_audio': question_audio_base64,
            'answer_audio': answer_audio_base64,
        })
    return JsonResponse({'error': 'Invalid request'}, status=400)

def home(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect('all_decks')
    else:
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = AuthenticationForm(request, data=request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                user = authenticate(username=form.cleaned_data['username'], password=form.cleaned_data['password'])
                if user is not None:
                    login(request, user)
                    return redirect('home')
        else:
            form = AuthenticationForm()
        return render(request, 'login.html', {'form': form})

def show_all_cards(request):
    c_list = Card.objects.all()
    context = {'list_of_cards': c_list}
    return render(request, 'show_all_cards.html', context)

def delete_card(request, card_id):
    card_to_delete = Card.objects.get(id=card_id)
    card_to_delete.delete()
    return redirect('show_all_cards')

def show_all_decks(request):
    d_list = Deck.objects.all()
    context = {'list_of_decks': d_list}
    return render(request, 'all_decks.html', context)

def delete_deck(request, deck_id):
    deck_to_delete = Deck.objects.get(id=deck_id)
    deck_to_delete.delete()
    return redirect('all_decks')

class DeckCreate(CreateView):
    form_class = DeckForm
    model = Deck

    def form_valid(self, form):
        f = form.save(commit=False)
        f.creator = self.request.user
        f.save()
        return super().form_valid(form)

import os
from django.conf import settings
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, redirect, render

def generate_audio(text, output_path):
    # Code to generate audio from text
    pass

def create_cards(request, deck_id):
    deck = get_object_or_404(Deck, pk=deck_id)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        formset = CardFormSet(request.POST, instance=deck)
        if formset.is_valid():
            cards = formset.save(commit=False)
            for card in cards:
                card.deck = deck

                # Generate audio files for the question and answer
                question_audio_path = os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, 'audio', f'question_{card.id}.mp3')
                answer_audio_path = os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, 'audio', f'answer_{card.id}.mp3')

                generate_audio(card.question, question_audio_path)
                generate_audio(card.answer, answer_audio_path)

                card.question_audio = os.path.join('audio', f'question_{card.id}.mp3')
                card.answer_audio = os.path.join('audio', f'answer_{card.id}.mp3')

                card.save()

            return redirect('create_cards', deck_id=deck_id)

    else:
        formset = CardFormSet(instance=deck)

    return render(request, 'create_cards.html', {'formset': formset, 'deck': deck})

def show_deck(request, deck_id):
    deck = Deck.objects.get(pk=deck_id)
    c_list = Card.objects.filter(deck=deck)
    context = {'list_of_cards': c_list, 'deck': deck}
    return render(request, 'show_deck.html', context)

def rehearse_deck(request, deck_id):
    deck = Deck.objects.get(pk=deck_id)
    c_list = Card.objects.filter(deck=deck)
    context = {
        'list_of_cards': c_list,
        'deck': deck,
        'audio_enabled': request.GET.get('audio_enabled', False)
    }
    return render(request, 'rehearse_deck.html', context)

def save_for_study(request, deck_id):
    user = request.user
    deck = Deck.objects.get(pk=deck_id)
    studyset, created = StudySet.objects.get_or_create(student=user)
    if not StudentDeck.objects.filter(deck=deck, student=user).exists():
        s = StudentDeck()
        s.studyset = studyset
        s.student = user
        s.deck = deck
        s.save()
    return redirect('show_my_studyset')

def show_my_studyset(request):
    studyset = StudySet.objects.get(student_id=request.user.id)
    deck_list = StudentDeck.objects.filter(studyset_id=studyset.id)
    context = {'studyset': studyset, 'deck_list': deck_list}
    return render(request, 'my_studyset.html', context)

def remove_from_studyset(request, studentdeck_id):
    deck_to_remove = StudentDeck.objects.get(id=studentdeck_id)
    deck_to_remove.delete()
    return redirect('show_my_studyset')

def leitner(request, deck_id):
    deck = Deck.objects.get(pk=deck_id)
    c_list = Card.objects.filter(deck=deck)
    context = {'list_of_cards': c_list}
    return render(request, 'leitner_deck.html', context)

html
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load static %}

{% block content %}
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        {% for card in list_of_cards %}
        <div class="rehearse_card" id="card-{{ card.id }}">
            <div class="card text-center" style="width: 30rem;">
                <img src="{% static "images/FlashCardImage.svg" %}" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <div class="card-front">
                        <h4 class="card-title-question">Q: {{ card.question }}</h4>
                        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" onclick="flipCard({{ card.id }})">Flip Card</button>
                        <button class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm" onclick="toggleTextToSpeech({{ card.id }})">Text to Speech</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-back" style="display: none;">
                        <h5 class="card-text-answer">A: {{ card.answer }}</h5>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="card-footer">
                    <small class="text-muted">{{ card.id }} {{ card.deck.title }} · {{ card.deck.subject }}</small>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    function flipCard(cardId) {
        const cardFront = document.querySelector(`#card-${cardId} .card-front`);
        const cardBack = document.querySelector(`#card-${cardId} .card-back`);
        cardFront.style.display = cardFront.style.display === 'none' ? 'block' : 'none';
        cardBack.style.display = cardBack.style.display === 'none' ? 'block' : 'none';
    }

    function toggleTextToSpeech(cardId) {
        fetch(`{% url 'text_to_speech' deck_id=deck.id card_id=cardId %}`, {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'X-CSRFToken': '{{ csrf_token }}',
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({}),
        })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
            if (data.question_audio && data.answer_audio) {
                const questionAudio = new Audio(`data:audio/mpeg;base64,${data.question_audio}`);
                const answerAudio = new Audio(`data:audio/mpeg;base64,${data.answer_audio}`);

                questionAudio.play();
                questionAudio.addEventListener('ended', () => {
                    answerAudio.play();
                });
            } else {
                console.error('Error:', data.error);
            }
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.error('Error:', error);
        });
    }
</script>
{% endblock %}

